# How to scale a single react codebase to multiple firebase projects?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have a react web application using firebase backend. I currently have 2 projects, one for testing and one for production. I use 2 different branches and deploy them manually using the firebase CLI. I want to scale the production site and have 10+ spin offs. 
I would like to have a different firebase project for each site using its own database/functions.

What is the best approach to do so? Can I use custom .env. files, one for each project, to store the project configurations?

How can I deploy to multiple projects using a single command like "firebase deploy production" which deploys a build using the right environment configuration to each project.

Comment: Have a look at Firebase CLI deploy targets: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets, which seem made for what you are trying to do.

Comment: With deploy targets I can specify multiple hosting sites of the same project. Since I can only have one firestore per project, I need these hosting sites to be part of different projects. Do I need to create a custom script which uses "firebase use" to switch between projects and deploy them individually?

Comment: Hmmm.... good point. You could indeed script changing the project.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following approach:

1.Create a firebase project for each spin-of (having its own hosting url and db)

2.Replace the firebase config variables like projectId and api-key with env variables:

```
const projectId = process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID;
const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY;

const config = {
  apiKey,
  projectId,
  authDomain: `${projectId}.firebaseapp.com`,
  databaseURL: `https://${projectId}.firebaseio.com`,
  storageBucket: `${projectId}.appspot.com`,
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

3.set the env variables independently for each project for the build and deploy it while specifying the project using the option `-P`

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=<projectId> REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY=<key> yarn build && firebase deploy --only hosting -P <projectId>
```

4.execute the cmd for each project (probably possible to put them all in one script to be able to deploy to all projects with a single command)